# how to edit and preview song chords using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one requirement of edit and preview the songs chords. Like in this example https://songbase.life/admin/example . Actually this built in react js but i want to implement same in jquery or javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="InputTEXT">
        <textarea id="editText" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div id="preview">
       //Preview here 
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you open the link on the left side user is typing and preview is on right side...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editText').keyup(function(){
       $('#editText).val();
       $('#preview').html($('#editText).val());
   })
})
```

I want to set the chords positing like mentioned in the above example.
Note :- i want songs text to be formatted in preview same way in the above example link

Comment: simply use `$('#preview').html($('#editText').val());`

Comment: @Swati did you understand my requirement

Comment: i want songs text to be formatted in  same way in the above example link

Comment: i need some logic where [C] this portion of text move up.. see this link https://songbase.life/admin/example

Comment: You are asking for the entire code, not for help.

Answer (score 2):

Copying over the text from the source to the destination is rather simple as @Swati mentioned, but formatting it will be significantly more difficult. It looks like the example provided uses Markdown for the baseline formatting and expands upon it for use with music.

Writing the tool to transform your text from pure text to Markdown from scratch is a bit overkill, so I would recommend using something like [Marked](https://marked.js.org/) to get you started. From there, you should be able to extend the tool for use in music as they do in the example using the [`marked.use()` functionality](https://marked.js.org/using_pro).

Building in the entirety of this functionality is going to require significant effort, but to get you started I've added an example of how to use Marked below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $source.keyup(transformText)
})

const $source = $('#editText')
const $dest = $('#preview')

function transformText() {
  const markdown = marked($source.val());
  $dest.html(markdown)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="InputTEXT">
        <textarea id="editText" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div id="preview">
       //Preview here 
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Edit

I didn't have anything better going on tonight, so here's an example of how to manually replace chords. This does not cover stanzas, lines, or links, but it's the best I can do to get you started on the solution.

The basic flow is as follows:

- Wait for the textfield to change, then trigger the transformation
- Use Marked to handle the basic Markdown functionality
- Look for chord word combinations with the format [chord]word
- Fill in template and replace each instance of [chord]word with the template
- Set the output to our new markdown

The CSS comes straight from the example website and requires a bit of knowledge regarding [data attributes](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/) and [pseudo-elements](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $source.keyup(transformText)
    transformText()
})

const $source = $('#editText')
const $dest = $('#preview')

function transformText() {
  let markdown = marked($source.val());
  markdown = replaceChordWords(markdown)
  
  $dest.html(markdown)
}

function replaceChordWords (input) {
  let markdown = input
  
  const chordWordRegex = /\[(.*?)\]\w+/g
  markdown = markdown.replaceAll(chordWordRegex, (input) => {
    const chordRegex = /\[(.*?)\]/
    const inputSplit = input.split(chordRegex).filter(x => x !== '')
    
    return `<span class="chord-word">
              <span class="chord" data-uncopyable-text="${inputSplit[0]}"></span>
              ${inputSplit[1]}
            </span>`
  })
  
  return markdown
}
```

```css
.chord-word {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: relative;
}

.chord {
  color: #1f45ff;
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  white-space: wrap;
}

[data-uncopyable-text]::after {
  content: attr(data-uncopyable-text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="InputTEXT">
        <textarea id="editText" class="form-control" rows="5">
You can enter [C]chords in [Am]the ex[F]act place you want them [G]with squ[E7]are b[C]rackets like this.
        </textarea>
     </div>
     <div id="preview">
       //Preview here 
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you guys not understanding the question

Comment: see the preview output of your and check the output of above link that i mentioned in question

Comment: i need some logic where [C] this portion of text move up.. see this link https://songbase.life/admin/example

Comment: I understand the question, but building out the functionality to include things like chords ([C], [Am], etc) or stanzas (1, 2, etc) as they do in the example is going to take significant work. Asking SO users to do all of that work is a bit much, what we can do is help get you started.

Comment: As I mentioned, the Marked library will assist with the formatting process and the marked.use() function will help you extend it into adding cords such as [C] or [Am].

Comment: its not working i pasted the same content . You can preview it and check the output

Comment: I added a further example to help you move towards your goal. Again, it doesn't cover everything, but should help get you started.

Comment: thanks @chase appericate your kind help.. is it possible can you do ful part as i am not good in javascript. Thanks

Comment: I'm happy to help, but am unwilling to write the entire thing. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Users generally try and help/teach those asking questions how to resolve their problems themselves. Asking a user on here to complete a long and difficult project for you is overstepping the bounds of what an average user is willing to do.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson  may be you can ask something about his budget ahahah :D anyway here is the component source [Github: SongDisplay](https://github.com/ReganRyanNZ/songbase/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/components/SongDisplay.jsx)

Comment: @Vixed  the link you shared is in react js